# Creating Objects in loop

Tags: c#, object, for-loop

Just Looking for a way to create some(20) objects from the same class in a loop
is there a way to do it?

i tried in a for look using a Loopcount Int as a num with no luck.. any idea?

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     Student[] aStudent = new Student[20];

     for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Please enter the 2 grades for student num " + i+ " \nif there is no grade , enter -1");
         aStudent[i].FirstGrade = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
         aStudent[i].SecondGrade = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
     }
}
```

Comment: You sure can.  First you need a programming language.  Then you need a class.  Then you need an example of your attempt.  Then we will have ideas.

Comment: sorry :) im a noob here i will edit the post

Comment: Can I make a valuable suggestion? Don't use raw arrays unless you have a very good reason to do so; you should be using List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

Answer (score 0):

You have created an array but have not initialized the items in the array.  The simplest change is to just create a new instance inside the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    aStudent[i] = new Student();
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the 2 grades for student num " + i+ " \nif there is no grade , enter -1");
    aStudent[i].FirstGrade = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    aStudent[i].SecondGrade = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: I would add the aStudent to a list of objects so you can use outside of your for loop